# Oracle SQL Trigger doesn't bring any value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table structure:

```
Product_Name    Product_Id    Product_Type
Car             123           A
House           ABC           B
Ball            UZY           B
```

and so on...
Product Id comes from two different Customer fed Tables (table A and table B, both with Product_Name and Product_id). Once they create a new row (insert) on any of their tables a sequence add a new (random) Product_Id.
I have a trigger that basically tries to look for that Product Id when a new row gets inserted on my table (for audit, reporting, etc purpose tables):

```
create or replace TRIGGER  "MY_INSERT_ID_TRIGGER" 
before insert on "MY_TABLE"                
for each row   

DECLARE

begin    

if :NEW.My_Product_Name is null and lower(:NEW.My_product_type) = 'A'
then
    SELECT DISTINCT Product_Id
    INTO :NEW.My_product_id
    FROM CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_TABLE_A
    --To remove special characters and spaces:
    WHERE lower( regexp_replace( replace(Product_name, ' ', '') , '[^a-zA-Z ]') )
    =
    lower( regexp_replace( replace(:NEW.My_Product_name, ' ', '') , '[^a-zA-Z ]') );

elsif  :NEW.PRODUCT is null and lower(:NEW.PRODUCT_TYPE) = 'B'
then

    SELECT DISTINCT Product_Id
    INTO :NEW.My_product_id
    FROM CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_TABLE_B
    --To remove special characters and spaces:
    WHERE lower( regexp_replace( replace(Product_name, ' ', '') , '[^a-zA-Z ]') )
    =
    lower( regexp_replace( replace(:NEW.My_Product_name, ' ', '') , '[^a-zA-Z ]') );

else null;
end if;

end;
```

My table structure as follows:

```
My_product_name    My_product_id    My_product_type
```

Both select work fine where run independently (out of the trigger), however, the trigger itself doesn't bring any value.
Anybody knows why?

Thanks

---

This would be the SQL structure:

```
create table CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_TABLE_A
(
Product_Name varchar2(300),
Product_id varchar2(300)
)

create table CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_TABLE_B
(
Product_Name varchar2(300),
Product_id varchar2(300)
)

create table MY_TABLE
(
My_product_name varchar2(300),
My_product_id varchar2(300),
My_product_type varchar2(300)
)

INSERT ALL
    INTO CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_TABLE_A (Product_Name, Product_id)  
VALUES('Product1-A', 123)
    INTO CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_TABLE_A (Product_Name, Product_id)  
VALUES('Product2-A', 123)
    INTO CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_TABLE_A (Product_Name, Product_id)  
VALUES('Product3-A', 123)

    INTO CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_TABLE_B (Product_Name, Product_id)  
VALUES('Product1-B', 'ABC')   
    INTO CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_TABLE_B (Product_Name, Product_id)  
VALUES('Product2-B', 'DEF')
    INTO CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_TABLE_B (Product_Name, Product_id)  
VALUES('Product3-B', 'GHI')
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
```

So Inserting 'Product1-A' into My_Table would return its Id as per the trigger (into my table column my_product_id).

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a complete setup that demonstrates the issue: both tables with sample data and sample `insert` that doesn't reflect changes

Comment: You don't seem to have changed the identifiers consistently, but at least in the first branch, you're checking if `:new.my_product_name` is null and only looking for the ID if it is; but then if it is, you try to compare the table_a value against it - so that can never match anything.

Comment: SQL Steps added for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: thanks Alex, something so small but so important. That did it, thanks!

Comment: Were you supposed to be checking `:NEW.My_Product_ID is null` rather than name? Just curious. Glad you got it working though.

Comment: Honestly, I thought I needed to include the null clause cause of being a new row.
That's not the case evidently, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

These will always fail:

`lower(:NEW.My_product_type) = 'A'`

`lower(:NEW.PRODUCT_TYPE) = 'B'`